# Where can I check the available memory (heap) of phone model

Tags: java-me, midlet, midp, j2mepolish, midp-2.0

Is there an online database where I can check the amount of available heap memory on a particular mobile phone ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.. But See this link for ur reference, this is only for nokia devices.

[Nokia devices...](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/?filter=all)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find this info on developer portal of exact vendor. Link to Nokia device specification is pointed above. 
Info about Sony Ericcson you can find here in pdf files: http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/search-downloads/docstools/1.706816/1.716594?cc=gb&lc=en
There are some third-party databases with handset specifications. For example, J2MEPolish device DB: http://devices.j2mepolish.org/interactivedb/welcome.faces